# big delete query giving timeout

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a delete query like this

```
DELETE c1
FROM tablename c1, tablename c2 
WHERE c1.rewardID > c2.rewardID AND 
      c1.transactionDate = c2.transactionDate AND 
      c1.orderID = c2.orderID
```

This is giving me timeout error both from php and phpmyadmin as there is a number of rows needs to be deleted. How can  I execute it without timeout error ?

The issue is it is showing Lost connection to MySQL server during query when I print mysql_error()

can anyone give a select version of this query so that I can iterate it through php and delete

Explain details :

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  c1  ALL     PRIMARY,rewardID    NULL    NULL    NULL    92966   
1   SIMPLE  c2  ALL     PRIMARY,rewardID    NULL    NULL    NULL    92966   Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: try to add limit in your query.

Comment: Please provide DDLs and the EXPLAIN for the SELECT version of this query

Comment: @SureshKamrushi how can I add limit there ?

Comment: @Strawberry I am also looking for it

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @SureshKamrushi there is one problem here. As I am using aliases for the table, mysql is treating it as multi table select and so I can't use LIMIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What  @Suresh Kamrushi say is like this. run LIMITed DELETE until there is no more rows.

```
DELETE c1
FROM tablename c1, tablename c2 
WHERE c1.rewardID > c2.rewardID AND 
      c1.transactionDate = c2.transactionDate AND 
      c1.orderID = c2.orderID
LIMIT 10000;
```

But JOIN is not optimized (nesseccery index is not created), LIMIT might not helpful. please post `EXPLAIN` output so that we can help you. run below query to check out how long takes.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tablename c1, tablename c2 
WHERE c1.rewardID > c2.rewardID AND 
      c1.transactionDate = c2.transactionDate AND 
      c1.orderID = c2.orderID
```

### EDITED

thanks, Have you tried this INDEX?

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX (orderID, tranasctionDate, rewardID);
```

and please post your `CREATE TABLE..` to see how  your `rewardID` look like.

### EDITED 2

last try. make sure 'set autocommit = 0; BEGIN' to rollback.

```
DELETE FROM tablename c1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tablename c2 
    WHERE c1.rewardID > c2.rewardID AND 
          c1.transactionDate = c2.transactionDate AND 
          c1.orderID = c2.orderIDl
);
```

Comment: I have added the explain details for the query you have given I mean the select query to take count

Comment: @AlwinAugustin I have just updated my answer. I guess there is no suitable INDEX. if index well designed, 'Rows' of second line should be 1 more little bit more than 1.

Comment: I have added the index now. But now also it is showing the same error. My rewardID is a bigint and it is the primary key

Comment: the count is 25877664 and I think this is the issue here. can we do any optimizations for my delete query ? or it will be helpful if you can suggest one. What I need to do is to delete all the duplicate recrods except one which has same timestamp and orderID

Comment: @AlwinAugustin What a huge! I think if SELECT completes fast, `DELETE` is slow, then LIMIT is choice. MySQL manual says "This can be used to ensure that a given DELETE statement does not take too much time. You can simply repeat the DELETE statement until the number of affected rows is less than the LIMIT value." if Alias is used, LIMIT can not be used?

Comment: @AlwinAugustin table has only '92,966' rows, but SELECT produces '25877664' so I updated my answer. can you try? and be careful

Comment: ha finally fixed it....used rewrdID> 1000 and so for the whole records . Now it is okay